# With bsdtar "--exclude", how to only exclude subdirectories?

Tags: tar, gnu, bsd

In GNU tar (i.e. `gtar`), the `--exclude` option with a glob only matches the subdirectories, but not the directory itself. For example, `--exclude test-tar/a/b/*` would exclude anything inside of `b`, but not `b` itself. However, `bsdtar` is excluding the directory itself as well. My question is how do I make `bsdtar` act the same as GNU in this regard?

Here is an example script the demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "\nGiven an archive that looks like this:"
bsdtar -tf test.tgz

echo -e "\nExtract the archive excluding test-tar/a/b/* using gtar"
rm -rf test-tar
gtar -xzf test.tgz --exclude 'test-tar/a/b/*'
file test-tar/a/b
file test-tar/a/b/B.txt

echo -e "\nExtract the archive excluding test-tar/a/b/* using bsdtar"
rm -rf test-tar
bsdtar -xzf test.tgz --exclude 'test-tar/a/b/*'
file test-tar/a/b
file test-tar/a/b/B.txt
```

This outputs:

```
Given an archive that looks like this:
test-tar/
test-tar/a/
test-tar/a/A.txt
test-tar/a/b/
test-tar/a/b/B.txt

Extract the archive excluding test-tar/a/b/* using gtar
test-tar/a/b: directory
test-tar/a/b/B.txt: cannot open `test-tar/a/b/B.txt' (No such file or directory)

Extract the archive excluding test-tar/a/b/* using bsdtar
test-tar/a/b: cannot open `test-tar/a/b' (No such file or directory)
test-tar/a/b/B.txt: cannot open `test-tar/a/b/B.txt' (No such file or directory)
```

My versions are `tar (GNU tar) 1.29` and `bsdtar 3.3.2`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this question, it's quite simple: add a backslash to the trailing forwardslash.

A command would look like this:

```
bsdtar -xzf test.tgz --exclude 'test-tar/a/b\/*'
```

Comment: This did not quite work for me: I had to add two backslashes: `--exclude 'test-tar/a/b\\/*' (using bsdtar 3.5.1)
`